# how to point my atulitbaldhamah.blogspot.in to subdomain blog.atulitbaldhama.com

Tags: blogs, blogger

I have created a blog on blogspot   Now i want that when any body open my blog atulitbaldhamah.blogspot it redirect to my subdomain blog.atulitbaldhama  or 
any body open blog.atulitbaldhama  it will point  atulitbaldhamah.blogspot ,

I read instruction that change CNAME and tried it but fail

I confused that CNAME will be add in domain registrar panel or I have to create sub domain in hosting panel and add CNAME ?

Please help me

Shailendra

Answer (score 0):

I got solution

remember one thing that you can purchase domain from any registrar

you can point your blogspot blog using web hosting panel by   opening your DNS control panel of main domain then add cname as per blogger guide line on root not in subdomain,

What I made mistake is : i created sub domain on my hosting panel

no need to create any sub domain in hosting panel

Thank